# Web API returns stack trace instead of my code in catch block

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, exception

I'm using ASP.net 4.8, Visual Studio 2019 V 16.4.3.

I am trying to get at an uploaded file from the user and save it. I am running the code inside of a try block, catching the necessary exceptions. Right now it is throwing an exception, jumping to my catch block, and then ignoring the code inside and returning the full stack trace. Why is it doing this?
I'd also love to know what I'm doing wrong in trying to access the uploaded file, but that's probably another question.

```
public IHttpActionResult EditBusinessLogoAndCategory(string businessID, string categoryName)
        {
try {
                var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
                foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
//... more code
}
            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new ReturnVM(ReturnVM.ReturnStatus.Failure, ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message, "Internal Error saving image."));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new ReturnVM(ReturnVM.ReturnStatus.Failure, ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message, "Internal Error saving image."));
            }
```

It jumps immediately from the foreach loop when it tries to access httpRequest.Files, to the last catch block. It stops there, then instead of returning my message, it returns this:

> {
> "Message": "An error has occurred.",
> "ExceptionMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
> "ExceptionType": "System.NullReferenceException",
> "StackTrace": "   at Prox.Controllers.BusinessController.EditBusinessLogoAndCategory(String
> businessID, String categoryName) in
> C:\Users\aaron\Desktop\Prox\Prox_API\Prox\Controllers\BusinessController.cs:line
> 382\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_2.b__2(Object
> instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object
> instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
> controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
> where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()"
> }

I even have the correct catch block for this, but it ignores that one. How is it skipping my catch block? Is this is a bug in Visual Studio?

Comment: The only reason to have two catch blocks - one for null reference and another for all other exceptions - is if you're going to do something different depending on which one it is. If you're going to do exactly the same thing either way then you can get rid of the first `catch`.

Comment: @ScottHannen True. I was just testing things out. I was getting a specific null reference exception, so I added that catch block, but copied the code from the previous catch, so it produced the same problem. I'm my own worst enemy.

Comment: It's better than having someone else be our worst enemy. Unless they're in prison or maybe about to die.

Answer (score 1):

you need to check if your InnerException is filled currectly...

try something like this

```
public IHttpActionResult EditBusinessLogoAndCategory(string businessID, string categoryName)
        {
             try {
                var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
                foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
             //... more code
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new ReturnVM(ReturnVM.ReturnStatus.Failure, ex.Message, "Internal Error saving image."));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new ReturnVM(ReturnVM.ReturnStatus.Failure, ex.Message, "Internal Error saving image."));
            }
        }
```

Comment: I was creating an exception in the exception catching.. genius. Thank you!

Comment: and also you dont need to catchs mate.. just one is more than enough